# how to call sidebar functionality when i click menu button in angular js

Tags: angular, button, menu, sidebar

```html
<div class="sidebar" translate>
  <ul id="sidebarnav" [ngClass]="{'show': isShowMenu}">
    <li
      [class.active]="showMenu === sidebarnavItem.title"
      *ngFor="let sidebarnavItem of sidebarnavItems"
      [routerLinkActive]="sidebarnavItem.submenu.length != 0 ? '' : 'active'"
    >
      <!-- <div class="nav-small-cap" *ngIf="sidebarnavItem.extralink === true">{{sidebarnavItem.title}}</div> -->
      <a
        [routerLink]="sidebarnavItem.class === '' ? [sidebarnavItem.path] : null"
        [ngClass]="[sidebarnavItem.class]"
        *ngIf="!sidebarnavItem.extralink;"
        (click)="addExpandClass(sidebarnavItem.title)"
      >
        <i [ngClass]="[sidebarnavItem.icon]"></i>
        <span class="hide-menu"
          >{{sidebarnavItem.title}}
          <span
            *ngIf="sidebarnavItem.label != '' "
            [ngClass]="[sidebarnavItem.labelClass]"
            >{{sidebarnavItem.label}}</span
          >
        </span>
      </a>
      <!-- Second level menu -->
      <ul
        class="collapse"
        *ngIf="sidebarnavItem.submenu.length > 0"
        [ngClass]="{'in' : showMenu === sidebarnavItem.title }"
      >
        <li
          *ngFor="let sidebarnavSubItem of sidebarnavItem.submenu"
          [class.active]="showSubMenu === sidebarnavSubItem.title"
          [routerLinkActive]="sidebarnavSubItem.submenu.length > 0 ? '' : 'active'"
        >
          <a
            [routerLink]="sidebarnavSubItem.submenu.length > 0 ? null : [sidebarnavSubItem.path]"
            [routerLinkActive]="sidebarnavSubItem.submenu.length > 0 ? '' : 'router-link-active'"
            [ngClass]="[sidebarnavSubItem.class]"
            *ngIf="!sidebarnavSubItem.extralink;"
            (click)="addActiveClass(sidebarnavSubItem.title)"
          >
            <i [ngClass]="[sidebarnavSubItem.icon]"></i>
            {{sidebarnavSubItem.title}}
          </a>
          <!-- Third level menu -->
          <ul
            class="collapse"
            *ngIf="sidebarnavSubItem.submenu.length > 0"
            [ngClass]="{'in' : showSubMenu === sidebarnavSubItem.title }"
          >
            <li
              *ngFor="let sidebarnavSubsubItem of sidebarnavSubItem.submenu"
              routerLinkActive="active"
              [ngClass]="[sidebarnavSubsubItem.class]"
            >
              <a
                [routerLink]="[sidebarnavSubsubItem.path]"
                *ngIf="!sidebarnavSubsubItem.extralink;"
                [routerLinkActive]="sidebarnavSubsubItem.submenu.length > 0 ? '' : 'router-link-active'"
              >
                <i [ngClass]="[sidebarnavSubsubItem.icon]"></i>
                {{sidebarnavSubsubItem.title}}
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- First level menu -->
    <li class="user-profile" [class.active]="showMenu === 'user'">
      <a
        class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark"
        href="javascript:void(0)"
        (click)="addExpandClass('user')"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="hide-menu">My profile </span>
      </a>
      <ul
        aria-expanded="false"
        class="collapse"
        [class.in]="showMenu === 'user'"
      >
        <li><a href="/users/profile/update">My Profile </a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void()" (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more details. Your code has lots of missing code

Comment: I want responsive sidebar , in mobile view my sidebar hide and show menubar only . if we click the menu bar it open the sidebar functionlity

Comment: my sidebar.module.ts  ngOnInit() {
    this.sidebarnavItems = ROUTES.filter(sidebarnavItem => sidebarnavItem);
    $(function () {
      $('.sidebartoggler').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#main-wrapper').hasClass('mini-sidebar')) {
          $('body').trigger('resize');
          $('#main-wrapper').removeClass('mini-sidebar');
        } else {
          $('body').trigger('resize');
          $('#main-wrapper').addClass('mini-sidebar');
        }
      });
    });
  }

Comment: Can you please provide the stackblitz link with your existing code?